# How to implement is_polymorphic_functor?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, decltype

I'm trying to implement `is_polymorphic_functor` meta-function to get the following results:

```
//non-polymorphic functor
template<typename T> struct X { void operator()(T); };

//polymorphic functor 
struct Y { template<typename T> void operator()(T); };

std::cout << is_polymorphic_functor<X<int>>::value << std::endl; //false
std::cout << is_polymorphic_functor<Y>::value << std::endl; //true
```

Well that is just an example.     Ideally, it should work for *any* number of parameters, i.e `operator()(T...)`. [Here are few more test cases](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=76ba03862a18526fd7082e0dda2f5c8d) which I used to test @Andrei Tita's solution which fails for two test-cases.

And I tried this:

```
template<typename F>
struct is_polymorphic_functor
{
  private:
     typedef struct { char x[1]; }  yes;
     typedef struct { char x[10]; } no;

     static yes check(...);

     template<typename T >
     static no check(T*, char (*) [sizeof(functor_traits<T>)] = 0 );            
  public:
     static const bool value = sizeof(check(static_cast<F*>(0))) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

which attempts to make use of the following implementation of `functor_traits`:

```
//functor traits
template <typename T>
struct functor_traits : functor_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>{};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct functor_traits<R(C::*)(A...) const> : functor_traits<R(C::*)(A...)>{};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct functor_traits<R(C::*)(A...)>
{
   static const size_t arity = sizeof...(A) };

   typedef R result_type;

   template <size_t i>
   struct arg
   {
      typedef typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<A...>>::type type;
   };
};
```

which gives the following error for polymorphic functors:

```
error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
```

How to fix this issue and make `is_polymorphic_functor` work as expected?

Comment: Pretty sure it's actually impossible to test for an arbitrary number of functions with a semi-fixed signature like `polymorphic2`, but I don't see the use-case for it. What useful information will it provide, if you don't already know the signature?

Comment: So, `struct test { void operator()(int) {}; void operator()(double) {}; };` is polymorphic, but is `struct crazy {
   template<typename T>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value>::type operator()( T ) {};
};` polymorphic?  I suspect you have asked someone to solve the halting problem.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_polymorphic_functor
{
private:
    //test if type U has operator()(V)
    template<typename U, typename V>
    static auto ftest(U *u, V* v) -> decltype((*u)(*v), char(0));
    static std::array<char, 2> ftest(...);

    struct private_type { };

public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(ftest((T*)nullptr, (private_type*)nullptr)) == 1;
};
```

Comment: Er, SFINAE? It's not dissimilar to your own code, so I'm not sure what it is which you can't understand.

Comment: This already works if it's defined as `template<typename... T> void operator()(T...)`.

Comment: It fails for other test : http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=76ba03862a18526fd7082e0dda2f5c8d

Comment: @Nawaz That is almost, but not quite, entirely unlike your initial request.

Comment: You can trivially extend the class to check for a (finite) number of templated parameters (which would pass, say `polymorphic3`), but not the insanity which is `polymorphic2` and its like.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't work if author of polymorphic functor imposes some SFINAE requirement on `T` itself (such as `T` must be derived from `Xyz` etc). +1 anyway, for the good attempt.

Comment: @Nawaz: And we cannot possibly include all possible varieties of programming code in an SO answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But knowing when a solution doens't work, is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the nonpolymorphic functors don't have an overloaded `operator()`:

```
template<typename T>
class is_polymorphic_functor {
  template <typename F, typename = decltype(&F::operator())>
  static constexpr bool get(int) { return false; }
  template <typename>
  static constexpr bool get(...) { return true; }

public:
  static constexpr bool value = get<T>(0);
};
```

Comment: +1. Awesome. Passed ALL the test cases so far : http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=81d0ed33a98c878fff9921a20d4c412b

Comment: @Nawaz: Please add these "testcases" into your question if they are important.

Comment: Is `struct empty {};` polymorphic?  :)

Comment: This doesn't test if the class HAS a polymorphic operator(), merely that it doesn't have a non-polymorphic one.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<template<typename>class arbitrary>
struct pathological {
  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if< arbitrary<T>::value >::type operator(T) const {}
};
```

The above functor is non-polymorphic iff there is exactly one T such that `arbitrary<T>::value` is true.

It isn't hard to create an `template<T>` functor which is true on `int` and possibly `double`, and only true on `double` if (arbitrary computation returns 1).

So an uncompromising `is_polymorphic` is beyond the scope of this universe.

If you don't like the above (because it clearly takes more than just `int`, other types simply fail to find an overload), we could do this:

```
template<template<typename>class arbitrary>
struct pathological2 {
  void operator()(int) const {}
  template<typename T>
  typename std::enable_if< arbitrary<T>::value >::type operator(T) const {}
};
```

where the second "overload" is tested, and if there are no T such that it is taken, then the first overload occurs for every single type.